# Find the rate of convergence of the following sequences.

Tags: numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

**Reference Textbook:** *A Friendly Introduction to Numerical Analysis-* *Brian Bradie.*

**Rate of convergence**

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence that converges to $x$. If there exists a sequence $\{y_n\}$ that converges to $0$,a positive constant $\lambda>0$ (independent of $n$) and a Natural number $N$ such that

> $\forall n\geq N  \implies |x_n-x|<\lambda |y_n|$

Then we say $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence that converges to $x$ with a rate of convergence $O(y_n).$

1. What is the rate of convergence of *Newton-Raphson* Method(If the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} converges)$ ?
   Is it possible to find the rate of convergence to *Newton-Raphson* method? This was the question came to my mind when the author misses the rate of convergence of **Newton Raphson method** and **Secant Method**.

2.What is the rate of convergence of *Secant* Method?

**My attempt**

1. Let for the initial guess $x_0$, $x_n$ converges to $x.$

$ |x_n-x|=|x_{n-1}-\frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}-x|=|\frac{(x_{n-1}-x)f'(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}|$

I am not able to find $\lambda, N $ and $\{y_n\}$.

2. For Secant Method,

$ |x_n-x|=|x_{n-1}-f(x_{n-1})\cdot \frac{(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})}{f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2})}-x|=|(x_{n-1}-x)-f(x_{n-1})\cdot \frac{(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})}{f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2})}|=| \frac{(x_{n-1}-x)\cdot (f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2}))-f(x_{n-1})\cdot (x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})}{f(x_{n-1})-f(x_{n-2})}|$

I am not able to reduce further.
I am not able to find $\lambda, N $ and $\{y_n\}$.

Comment: Here is the answer for the case of Newton Raphson method https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/lectures/L10-Rates-of-conv-Newton.pdf

Comment: A rough method that gets the right answer for secant method: Write $e_n = x_n - x$. Do Taylor expansion around the root $x$ to small order to get a recurrence relation for $e_n$. Hypothesize a relation $e_{n + 1} = \lambda e_n^p$. Use this to solve the recurrence for $p$.

Comment: In both cases insert the Taylor series of $f$ at the root $x$. Use suitable remainder terms to get sharp bounds.